# How to decrease spacing between subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, patchwork

I have the following plot, I use ggplot2 and patchwork for a panel plot.
Each row makes predictions about different target datasets so I thought it could be
helpful to have a title for each row, which I just created with an empty `ggplot + annotate()`
Here is how it currently looks:
[image]

**Code for the Example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) +
  ggtitle("Plot 1")

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) +
  ggtitle("Plot 2")

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) +
  ggtitle("Plot 3")

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(gear)) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  ggtitle("Plot 4")

ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "Predictions on Dataset 1",size=8) +
  theme_void() -> title1
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "Predictions on Dataset 2",size=8) +
  theme_void() -> title2


title1 /
  (p1 | p2) /
  title2 /
  (p3 | p4) +
  plot_annotation(
    tag_levels = list(c("","A.1) Model Name 1", "B.1) Model Name 2", "","A.2) Model Name 1", "B.2) Model Name 2")),
    theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 24))
  ) &
  theme(

  )
```

**Question**
How can I reduce the space between the `title1` and `title2` and the other plots?

**Desired Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title1 / (p1 | p2) /
  title2 / (p3 | p4) +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1,6,1,6)) +
  ....
```

[image]

And you can adjust the text size in your `title1` and `title2` to make those more consistent with the other text. Here's with `size = 5`:

[image]